# 425 Unable to build data connection: No route to host

Tags: batch-file, ftp

Firewall is turned off but still it is not able to execute put commend on ftp

```
ftp>cd /web
250 CWM command successful
ftp>binary
200 Type set to I
ftp>put C:\sample.xml
200 PORT command successful
425 Unable to build data connection: No route to host
```

Comment: Let me pull out the crystal ball and see what it says.. Oh, it says you should show us your code by editing your answer.

Comment: In my case it makes 0-sized files on the server (it can create directories fine)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your script works in active mode, e.g. the client gives the server a client side ip and port using the PORT command and the server tries to connect to it. Because the server replies, that it has no route to your host my guess is, that

- you are in an internal network, e.g. using a private IP which is not directly accessible from the internet. This IP is used in the PORT command.
- the server is on the internet
- from the internet the server of course can not connect into a private network, thus you get this error message

Fix: use passive mode (e.g. you should see a PASV not a PORT command)

Comment: i'm using passive mode

Comment: No you don't. From your output it is clearly visible that PORT is used. But PORT is only send with active mode, and with passive mode a PASV command is send.

Comment: i tried with passive mode as well (quote pasv) , but it is not workings.I am using now CLR procedure  to upload the file , but from  command prompt there are  still problems ...

Comment: What are the errors with passive mode? If both server and client are behind NAT or restrictive but dumb firewall (without special support for ftp) it is usually impossible to get ftp working because of the data connections to dynamic ports.

Comment: connection closed by remote host

Comment: Yes, this might be a firewall blocking the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Windows `ftp.exe` operates in `passive` mode and your FTP server may need `active` FTP transfers.

Test your commands on a different FTP server to see if it works elsewhere.

Comment: from another ip address same bat file works properly